# Crystal reports - how to handle null while using group

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to know which is the best way to include null values in the report while using the below groups. My below report uses two groups one below other, Month group is under the field group. I have given the formula for the Field Group A; and for for the month I have used options to fetch the months from the specific date field [source is excel file]  in ascending order. Since there are no data for group A - 1 records for October month I don't see any data whereas I would want to show the month with NA as result.

## Report looks like below currently

```
Field GROUP -A - 1

Month       Result

11-2012       xxx

12-2012       xxx

Field Group A- 0

Month        Result


10-2012        xxx

11-2012        XXX

12-2012        xxx
```

## But I would like the report to be as below:

```
Field GROUP -A - 1

Month       Result

10-2012       NA

11-2012       xxx

12-2012       xxx

Field Group A- 0

Month        Result


10-2012        xxx

11-2012        XXX

12-2012        xxx
```

Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports can't show the data, because there isn't any data to show.

There's only one instance I'm aware of where Crystal Reports will auto-fill `NULL` data, and that's when using a crosstab, which really doesn't appear to fit your needs or desired output.

You'll have to supply the "N/A" value for 10-2012, Group 1 in your query, possibly by using some table of dates to outer join against.